# Datagridview gets emptied after column header iteration

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a winform where I retrieve data from SQL DB into datagridview and then export it to XML file. Data returned from DB has column names (headers) in English, however, in my form, they are in different language, which I would like to be included in the export XML file. For this purpose I iterate through datagridview and assign its column names to to the datatable which is then exported to XML file.
This is my code:

```
private void ExportToXml(DataGridView repGrid)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.DataTable data = (System.Data.DataTable)repGrid.DataSource;
                data.TableName = "LoanPortfolioReport";

                for (int i = 0; i < repGrid.ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    data.Columns[i].ColumnName = repGrid.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                                        
                }
                         
                //export file:
                SaveFileDialog.Filter = "XML|*.xml";
                SaveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
                SaveFileDialog.FileName = "LoanPortfolio_" + loanPortfolioDatePicker.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xml";

                if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {

                    data.WriteXml(SaveFileDialog.FileName);

                }



            }
```

This is my datagridview before export:
[image]

And this happens after I iterate through column headers:
[image]

If I omit the column header iteration part, then datagridview doesn't get empty. I would appreciate suggestions regarding this behavior.

Comment: Clone the DataTable if you mean to modify something non trivial as the `ColumnName`.

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks, it helped (I actually copied the DataTable into a new one), but I still don't understand the reason behind the above-mentioned behavior. Could you suggest what was causing it?

Comment: A DataTable is a Reference Type. In this: `DataTable data = (DataTable)repGrid.DataSource;`, `data` is a reference to the DataTable that is the DataSource of your DGV. Each Column of the DGV is linked to the DataSource based on the `DataPropertyName` property, which defines the name of the Column in the data source that provides the data for DGV's Column. So, if you change the name of the source Column...